# Google Visualization API (Charts) tooltips not working in Firefox

Tags: google-visualization

A **google.visualization.BarChart** will not show tooltips for me in Firefox, but shows them in Chrome.

I am using Firefox 4.0.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be related to issue 598 "Google Chart Tools: tooltip/line not shown on firefox using base tag" at [google-visualization-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=598) which is reproduced when a [base tag](http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/base/) differs from a page location.

A possible solution could be to use jQuery to change the href attr of the tag.

```
jQuery("base").attr('href', document.location);
chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: There's a function providing a workaround which doesn't mess with the base tag on the issue now:
http://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=598#c7

Answer (score 0):

I think that it will be better to add base-tag in frame-drawing, like that

```
chart.draw(data, options);

     jQuery(document).ready
     (
      function()
      {
       jQuery('iframe[name^=Drawing_Frame]').contents().find('head').append('<base href="'+document.location+'"></base>')
      }
     );
```

It works for me

Comment: From issue 598: "The drawing is now based on inline SVG and no longer a Drawing_Frame iframe element."